# Laravel DB::statement CREATE DATABASE can't add parameters (prepared statement?)

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, prepared-statement

I am using Laravel 5.3 PHP framework and I need additional guidance on how to create a database using DB::statement method, I can do it simply like this, but I'm aware of SQL injection possibility:

```
DB::statement('CREATE DATABASE new_database_name');
```

However I want to do something like this:

```
DB::statement('CREATE DATABASE :db_name', ['db_name' => 'new_database_name']);
```

I'm not sure why the second example doesnt work. I've been reading laravel documentation, and this sort of thing works with DB::insert, DB::select, but what about DB::statement

Comment: Do you get any errors? Does your MySQL user have the correct permissions to add new database? Check Laravel logs, PHP logs and MySQL logs and post here more details.

Comment: That's really weird. I also get syntax error if I try your second example with bindings, and the same for ? bindings. But the first one works fine. The answer below about getConnection() clearly doesn't work on 5.2+ at least, it's way too old for that.

Comment: Alright, I found the answer. You can't supply variables for database names, since that's not what they're there for. For more information, check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17590594/create-database-with-pdo-in-php

Comment: Ahh, understandable. If you want, you can make an answer, I will approve it.

Comment: Appreciate it, but I don't want to get credit for somebody else's answer. :)

Comment: That's reasonable :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually you can't use bind parameters on CREATE or DROP. Have to be used like that e.g.:

```
DB::statement("CREATE DATABASE {$newDatabase}");
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

A possible reason for your code not to work might be not establishing the connection with the Database.
To Create new table Use the Following Code Snippet.

```
DB::getConnection()->statement('CREATE DATABASE :schema', array('schema' => $schemaName));
```

For A detailed description Use the Following Link at laravel.io.
http://laravel.io/forum/09-13-2014-create-new-database-and-tables-on-the-fly

Comment: getConnection() as far as I know is unavailable in laravel 5.3, the forum link is for 2014, so it's old

Comment: Sorry Then.. I didn't try this with the new version.. But there shhould be a way to make the connection. Isn't it? .env or config.php files can't do this since you are creating the database at run time. Pardon if i'm wrong.

Comment: The connection actually works, it's just that You can't use prepared statements on DATABASE CREATE in general. Joel Hinz has given me the  right direction to the answer, it's up in the comments of my question.

I'm not sure how it managed to work in old versions.

Comment: Ah got it.. Thanks.. :)